# Trouble understanding the definition of a parabola: Spivak Calculus Chapter 4-21b

Tags: geometry, definition

Spivak's problem reads as follows:

> Given the horizontal line $L$ defined by $g(x)=\gamma$ and a point $P=(\alpha, \beta)$ not on $L$ so that $\gamma \neq \beta$, show that the set of all points $(x,y)$ equidistant from $P$ and $L$ is the graph of a function of the form $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

I interpreted this question as:

$W:=\{\langle x,y \rangle \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R\  |\  \exists \langle x^*, \gamma \rangle \in L \Big [ \sqrt{(x-\alpha)^2+(y-\beta)^2}=\sqrt{(x-x^*)^2+(y-\gamma)^2}\Big ]\}$

After consulting Spivak's solution manual, it is clear Spivak wants the reader to only observe the points on the line $L$ that have the following relationship to a given ordered pair in $W$: $x=x^*$.

i.e. Spivak's set looks like this:

$W':=\{\langle x,y \rangle \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R\  |\   \sqrt{(x-\alpha)^2+(y-\beta)^2}=\sqrt{(y-\gamma)^2}\}$

I've seen various definitions online which echo Spivak's above definition...and the point of confusion always seems to be the statement: "**Equidistant From a Line** (directrix)". Consider my quick sketches below:

[image: First]

[image: Second]

Hopefully these sketches are sufficiently elucidating.

So what exactly does it *formally* mean to be "**equidistant from a line**?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

Comment: The distance to $P$ must be equal to the *perpendicular* distance to the line.

Comment: @Tavish ahhh, so this is a definition?

Comment: @S.Cramer It’s as simple as that.

Comment: @Tavish cheers~

Comment: The meaning of "equidistant from a line" is irrelevant to the exercise in Spivak. It never says anything is "equidistant from a line." It says that there is a set of points that is equidistant from a point **and** a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distance from a line is defined as perpedicular distance to the line.

$$\sqrt{(x-\alpha)^2+(y-\beta)^2}=|y-\gamma| = \sqrt{(y-\gamma)^2}$$

Comment: So the notion of "perpendicular" has to actually precede the notion of "line-to-point distance"?

Comment: it is the shortest distance, of which we can prove it to be the perpedicular distance. it's consistent with the definition of a point to a set. $d(x, A)=\inf \{d(x, a): a \in A\}$